# Using D on Linux how do i determine if a file is hidden?

Tags: file, attributes, d

I'm creating a simple file walker to list some files and need to omit hidden files from the results. I'm currently doing something like this:

```
private void Walk()
{
    this.Files          = [];
    this.Directories    = [];
    DirIterator Entries = dirEntries(this.Directory, SpanMode.depth, this.FollowSymLinks);

    foreach (DirEntry Entry; Entries)
    {
        version(Windows)
        {
            uint Attributes = Entry.attributes();
            if (Attributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        version(linux)
        {
            // ?????
        }

        if (Entry.isFile())
        {
            this.Files ~= Entry.name;
            this.NumberOfFiles++;
        }

        if (Entry.isDir())
        {
            this.Directories ~= Entry.name;
            this.NumberOfDirectories++;
        }
    }

    this.Walked = true;
}
```

The windows section seems to work fine but what do i need to do for the Linux section to determine if a file is hidden?

Comment: Linux doesn't really have hidden file. By convention configuration file start with a period. File browsers will hide these by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In linux files/directories are hidden if they are prefaced with a `.` so check to see if the file/directory name starts with a `.`

for example

`.m2/` and `.somefile.txt` would be hidden on linux where as `m2/` and `somefile.txt` would not.

Comment: Is this the only way that files are defined as hidden on Linux?

Comment: @GaryWilloughby as was previously stated, it is the only way